# Split up a large file based on context heading

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've a large file (over 20 MB) and need to split into smaller trunks. The input.txt file looks like this:

```
Rate: AAAA
.....
.....
....

Rate: AAAB

.....
.....
....

Rate: AAAC
.....
```

and I'd like output to be:

```
AAAA.txt:
Rate: AAAA
.....
.....
....

AAAB.txt:
Rate: AAAB

.....
.....
....

AAAC.txt:
Rate: AAAC
.....
```

My shell script is very slow because it is reading the file line by line, how can I improve it.

```
INPUT=input.txt; key="Rate"
cat $INPUT | while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == *"$key"*  ]]; then
        name=`echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f2`
    fi
    echo "$line" >> "./tmp/$name"
done
```

Comment: I can't see many ways the script can really be improved (except for removing the useless use of cat - have the file piped into the while loop after the done instead of piping cat's output).

Comment: I've been thinking about using array, then for example using 'sed -n 1,6p input.txt' to extract file from line 1 to 6. To fine the line number has the Rate keyword is simple 'idx=$(grep -n $key $INPUT | cut -d: -f1)'. But I don't know how to put this into a loop so that the 'sed can' be used.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^Rate: / {
  if (fn) close(fn)
  fn = $2 ".txt"
  }
{ print > fn }' infile
```

Corrected.

Edit: Assuming the temp_dir exists (see comments below):

```
awk '/^Rate: / {
  if (fn) close(fn)
  fn = "temp_dir/" $2 ".txt"
  }
{ print > fn }' infile
```

Comment: Will the `next` skip the line printing for the `Rate:` lines? I think Dean wanted those in the output files.

Comment: How can I keep the Rate line in the output file as well?

Comment: Man `awk(1)` is amazing. Five lines compared to my Ruby's seven lines, and I'd wager the `awk(1)` is just as fast. It kind of makes me want the full 20M file for testing. :)

Comment: Note that the following line is need only to limit the number of concurrently open files: `if (fn) close(fn)`. On modern systems with modern *awk* implementations (*GNU awk*, for example) it's not needed (so the script could be even shorter).

Comment: @Dimitre, how do I put the output file in a temp dir?

Answer (score 1):

Your process is not very slow because it reads the file line by line, but because it spawns two processes per line.  Split the work differently, and you'll be fine.  For example, having one process to identify the "Rate" lines, and one process per rate ought to speed things up drastically:

```
for rate in $( sed -n 's/^Rate: \(.*\)/\1/p' $INPUT )
do
  sed -n "/^Rate: $rate\$/,/^Rate/ {/^Rate: / {/$rate/!d}; p}" $INPUT >$rate.txt
done
```

Allowing yourself actual scripting languages (or keeping it with bash, but not spawning any child process any more) would let you traverse the file only once.  For example, in pure bash, this should cut it:

```
file=/dev/null
while read line
do
  rate=${line#Rate: }
  if [[ $line != $rate ]]; then file=$rate.txt
  else echo "$line" >> $file; fi
done <$INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that every single line involves executing the `echo` and `cut` commands:

```
    name=`echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f2`
```

(At least, I think the `echo` invoked there is the `/bin/echo` command rather than the shell builtin `echo`. I *know* the `cut` there is an external program.)

Also, the destination files are re-opened and re-closed (and written to without the benefit of the usual C standard IO buffering, unless those lines are *huge*) for every single line.

Switching to a different language that lets you do these operations without a `fork(2)`, `execve(2)`, `open(2)`, `write(2)`, and `close(2)` for every single line would be an improvement. Here's my shot in Ruby:

```
$ cat split.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

output = nil

File.open("input.txt").each { |line|
    if (line.match(/Rate: (.+)$/)):
        output = File.new("tmp/#{$1}", "a")
    end
    output.write(line)
}
$
```

I tested it on the toy input you gave, it seemed to get it all correct.